# Errors with Craft 2.3, Imagine and Imagick

Tags: assets, config, image-transforms

Does anyone else have the same issue?

Post the recent Craft 2.3 update all image transforms on my server (about 6 craft sites now) are throwing errors on new transforms.

Specifically write errors from the Imagine library's Imagick classes.

My directories are writable and these sites have been working for some time. No new updates on the server, standard Debian lamp stack.

Comment: Hey Tom, this question doesn't really meet the format of Stack Exchange. I'd recommend one of two things... Either separate your post into "problem/solution" (you can provide an answer to your own question), or simply delete the question and post it over on the [Google+ Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/106505340287442511226).

Comment: Sorry, bit of a stack exchange noob. Should I just delete then, as my solution isn't really a solution, more just information for a temporary fix...

Comment: I thought google+ was not used anymore?

Comment: No worries, welcome to SE! If you think the problem & solution have historical value (as in, could it help other folks who may find themselves in the same situation), then I'd actually recommend this: **Edit** your question, and trim it back to just the problem part, and then **answer** your own question, providing the solution. It's a somewhat common practice, and can really help someone else out in the future! Within a few days, you can even select your own answer as the correct solution (assuming no one suggests something even better).

Comment: Just done that, hopefully might help someone.

Comment: The Google+ community is still technically being used, though it is a shadow of its former self (which is a good thing, SE is way better). But not everything is a good fit for SE... People still chime in with feature requests, job offers, and even general topics for discussion. Fortunately, pretty much all of the troubleshooting has moved over to SE.

Answer (score 3):

I've tracked it down / fixed it by explictly selecting my 'imageDriver' in the config. The docs say this is a new setting in 2.3.

It seems the default of 'null' is calling 'imagick' but not working, whereas choosing 'imagick' in the config makes it work?