# Error when calling an image transform from matrix field

Tags: image-transforms

I'm trying to call an image via an image transform from a matrix field.

So when I do this:

```
{% if block.type == "standardImage" %}
  {% set image = block.imageFile.first() %}
  {% if image %}
      <img src="{{ image.url('generalImageTransform') }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('generalImageTransform') }}" 
      height="{{ image.getHeight('generalImageTransform') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I get this:

```
<img src="http://.../cpresources/transforms/1?x=DrK2WYEvg" width="600" height="601" alt="district">
```

So you can see the width, height and title are all being called successfully, but the image is broken on the web page.

And when I skip the transform and just use `{{ image.url() }}` the image is called successfully with

```
<img src="/images/general/district.png" width="600" height="601" alt="district">
```

Finally when I add this to the config file

```
'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,
```

I get a PHP error

```
Image “district.png” cannot be found.
```

I suspect then that the transformed image is unable to be created, but I don't know how to progress this idea, or if I am on the right track at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to have worked it out - by specifying

```
'imageDriver' => 'gd'
```

in the config. I first tried to specify 'imageDriver' => 'imagick', but I was getting path error messages so I'm guessing it is not installed on the PHP installation I am using.

More info at
[Errors with Craft 2.3, Imagine and Imagick](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6626/errors-with-craft-2-3-imagine-and-imagick)